# Can't update JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable which contains a list of item and a JPanel with some components. When I click to my button, I want all information of the selected item in the JTable will be loaded to the JPanel. At the first time, it work well but at the further times when I click to my button the Jpanel appears with empty component.

The code when clicking to my button:

```
jbtUpdateContract.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Object contractID = getValueOfSelectedRow(contractTable, 0);
            Contract contract = contractTransaction.getContractByID(Integer.parseInt(contractID.toString()));

            //Create Jpanel to display information
            jplUpdateContractForm.removeAll();
            jplUpdateContractForm = createContractForm(contract);
            jplUpdateContractForm.revalidate();

            //Modify contract frame
            jfrmUpdateContract.getContentPane().add(jplUpdateContractForm,
                    BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jfrmUpdateContract.setSize(400, 300);
            jfrmUpdateContract.setVisible(true);
            jfrmUpdateContract.setResizable(false);
        }
    });
```

And my `createContractForm` function:

```
public static JPanel createContractForm(Contract contract)
{
    JPanel jplContractForm = new JPanel(new SpringLayout());
    JLabel jlblAppointmentDate = new JLabel("Appointment date:", JLabel.TRAILING);
    jlblAppointmentDate.setName("jlblAppointmentDate");
    jplContractForm.add(jlblAppointmentDate);

    final JTextField jtxtAppointmentDate = new JTextField(15);
    jtxtAppointmentDate.setName("jtxtAppointmentDate");
    jtxtAppointmentDate.setText(contract.getAppointmentDate());
    jtxtAppointmentDate.setEditable(false);
    jtxtAppointmentDate.addMouseListener(appointmentDateMouseListener(jtxtAppointmentDate));        
    jlblAppointmentDate.setLabelFor(jtxtAppointmentDate);
    jplContractForm.add(jtxtAppointmentDate);
    jplContractForm.setOpaque(true);    

    //***Customer Cobobox
    JLabel jlblCustomer= new JLabel("Customer:", JLabel.TRAILING);
    jlblCustomer.setName("jlblCustomer");
    jplContractForm.add(jlblCustomer);

    final JComboBox  jcbxCustomer = new JComboBox();
    jcbxCustomer.setName("jcbxCustomer");
    //Load customers from DB to combobox
    Customer[] customers = customerTransaction.getAllCustomer();
    for(int i = 0; i < customers.length; i++)
        jcbxCustomer.addItem(customers[i]);
    System.out.println("----------CUSTOMER----------" + getIndexOfCustomerComboBoxItem(jcbxCustomer, contract.getCustomerSeq()));
    jcbxCustomer.setSelectedIndex(getIndexOfCustomerComboBoxItem(jcbxCustomer, contract.getCustomerSeq()));

    jlblCustomer.setLabelFor(jcbxCustomer);
    jplContractForm.add(jcbxCustomer);
    jplContractForm.setOpaque(true);
}
```

Please help me to explaint why the JPanel is empty as I describes above.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

The frame is already visible, so I don't think any of these lines of code will help.

```
jfrmUpdateContract.setSize(400, 300);
jfrmUpdateContract.setVisible(true);
jfrmUpdateContract.setResizable(false);
```

The revalidate() does nothing because you haven't added the panel to the frame yet. Try the revalidate() AFTER the panel has been added to the frame.

```
jplUpdateContractForm = createContractForm(contract);
//jplUpdateContractForm.revalidate();
jfrmUpdateContract.getContentPane().add(jplUpdateContractForm, BorderLayout.CENTER);
jplUpdateContractForm.revalidate();
```

If you need more help then post a proper `SSCCE`.

Comment: Thank you @camickr but It still does not work. Sorry, I don't know about SSCCE so how I do your advice.

Comment: @HoangNguyenhuu `Sorry, I don't know about SSCCE` - use Google?